# Get correct id for checkbox for update value in SQlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have trouble getting right on my checkbox . My problem is that I do not get the correct id from the database and therefore do not know the ID / series I will update the database. I have tried various suggestions here , but nothing would work. For the most part , I notice that the index is out of ...

When I used ArrayList to collect information, it was easy. I just used int position from my View to get the id...

I deleted all my attempts , therefore , there is currently no direct code that tries to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

```
**CustomAdapter.java**

    package com.example.com.hermods.shoppinglistwithdb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    DatabaseHandler DB_ADAPTER;
    long dbID;
    CheckBox chkbox;

    public CustomAdapter(DatabaseHandler DB_ADAPTER, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);

        this.DB_ADAPTER = DB_ADAPTER;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        dbID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String amount = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("amount")));
        int done = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("done"));

        TextView titleView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        titleView.setText(title);

        TextView amountView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);
        amountView.setText(String.valueOf(amount) + " " + context.getString(R.string.piece));

        chkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.itemDone);
        chkbox.setChecked(done != 0);

        titleView.setFocusable(false);
        titleView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    }


}
```

**List_Fragment.java**

```
public class List_Fragment extends ListFragment {

ShowDetail_Fragment showDetail;
CustomAdapter adapter;
DatabaseHandler DB_ADAPTER;

public List_Fragment(DatabaseHandler DB_ADAPTER) {
     this.DB_ADAPTER = DB_ADAPTER;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);


    return root;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long idDB) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.remove);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.remove, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).dbRemoveRow(idDB);
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).buildList();
                }
            });

            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
            dialog.create();
            dialog.show();

            return true;    
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor item = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).dbGetRow(id);

    showDetail = new ShowDetail_Fragment(item, id);
    FragmentTransaction FT = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FT.replace(R.id.layout, showDetail);
    FT.addToBackStack(null);
    FT.commit();
}
```

Comment: Place the code where you are inserting/Updating your DB. The cursor value as bindview will be autoincremented when it draws the view

Comment: You got the problem ?